# How to open url to another website in blazor?

Tags: html, blazor

I have a  tag that is defined dynamically, `<a href="url" target="_blank">@BarCode</a>`
But it opens looking for a page in my blazor build that has that url, so it comes up with web page not found.

How can I get it to navigate to an external url link?

Comment: Is the URL you're entering into the `href` attribute relative or complete? If it's relative (`/home/about`) then I'd expect it to look for the page in your blazor site... it needs to be a complete URL (`https://othersite.com/home/about`) for it to load the external link.

Comment: I used wikipedia for example and my program came up with http://en.m.wikipedia.org but it took me to an empty page of my app called /url

Comment: Have you simply made the mistake of just putting `href="url"` instead of `href="@url"` ?